# Excel, VB macro, MSCOMM and standard user

Tags: vba, excel, security, mscomm32

I have a device operated via Excel through com ports with MSComm32. Some macro linked to buttons on Excel forms used to make this device work properly. Up to these last days when it suddenly stopped working.

After some investigations, it seems there are some security considerations applied within Excel. The Excel file used up to now does not work anymore if Excel is runs as a standard user. An error message indicates the control cannot be created when trying to enter the creation mode, for example. But, if Excel is run as Administrator, then everything works fine.

Is there an easy way to fix this? For example granting access rights to standard user for the module MSComm32 OCX?

Thanks!

Comment: `it seems there are some security considerations applied within Excel` I doubt it was Excel. It is more of a Rights issue. Was any change made to user policies recently? This can only be confirmed with your IT team. I have faced similar issues in the past. It was only solved by elevating user rights. Also this question belongs to Superuser :)

Comment: @Siddharth Rout: no change was made to user policies. Installed on a fresh Windows install (with same installation package), the same issue occurs while we never add this issue before.

Comment: @MaxAuray Test if it is a rights issue by running it as administrator. If it runs there it is some kind of missing permission. Also the [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) might help to investigate which privileges are missing.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: As explained, it runs well as administrator. I will try to investigate further with Process Monitor. Thanks.